# Замена знаков препинания в строке на те же знаки с пробелом и обратно

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как в строке все знаки препинания поменять на них же, но с пробелом. А потом вернуть все обратно.

Comment: Если ничего не делать, то именно так и получится - все будет как было

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: в чем сложность у вас в данной задаче?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно воспользоваться регуляркой где в `[]` передать все необходимые знаки, далее воспользоваться ссылкой на группу а имено `$1` - является первой и единственной группой, напомню группой в регулярке называется выражение в `()`, пробел используется естественным образом.

Пример кода:

```
<?php 

$s = <<<EOD
Однажды,в студеную зимнюю пору
Я из лесу вышел;был сильный мороз.
Гляжу,поднимается медленно в гору
Лошадка,везущая хворосту воз.

EOD;


$s = preg_replace('/([;.,!?:])/', '$1 ', $s); // добавлен пробел после совпадения
echo $s;
/*
Однажды, в студеную зимнюю пору
Я из лесу вышел; был сильный мороз. 
Гляжу, поднимается медленно в гору
Лошадка, везущая хворосту воз.
*/

$s = preg_replace('/([;.,!?:]) /', '$1', $s); // ищем с пробелом но он не в группе
echo $s;

/*
Однажды,в студеную зимнюю пору
Я из лесу вышел;был сильный мороз.
Гляжу,поднимается медленно в гору
Лошадка,везущая хворосту воз.
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

php обычно в вэбе юзают в сочетании с html, js, css, полагаю у вас так же. а раз так попробуй поочередно применять:

```
white-space: pre;
white-space: normal;
```

но это конечно при условии что не обязательно удалять прям все пробелы.